# SlidingTabsBasic for having slidingmenu, tabs, gridview

Tags: android, tabs, slidingmenu

I want to use `http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html` to my project.
but it has a lot of errors that i cannot use it. have anybody the complete source code?